# how to keep the state of my widgets after scrolling?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm codeing an app with flutter an i'm haveing problems with the development. I'm trying to have a listview with a custom widget that it has  a favourite icon that represents that you have liked it product. I pass a boolean on the constructor to set a variables that controls if the icons is full or empty. When i click on it i change it state. It works awesome but when i scroll down and up again it loses the lastest state and returns to the initial state.
Do you know how to keep it states after scrolling?

Ty a lot <3

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return new LikeClass(liked: false);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LikeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool liked;//i want this variable controls how heart looks like

  LikeClass({this.liked});

  @override
  _LikeClassState createState() => new _LikeClassState();
}

class _LikeClassState extends State<LikeClass> {
  bool liked;
  @override
  void initState() {
    liked=widget.liked;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap:((){
              setState(() {
                liked=!liked;
                //widget.liked=!widget.liked;
              });
            }),
            child: new Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 24.0,
              color: liked?Colors.red:Colors.grey,
              //color: widget.liked?Colors.red:Colors.grey,//final method to control the appearance
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `ListView` code?

Comment: @JacobPhillips code below!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to store the state (favorite or not) in a parent widget. The `ListView.builder` widget creates and destroys items on demand, and the state is discarded when the item is destroyed. That means the list items should always be stateless widgets.

Here is an example with interactivity:

[image: example app]

```
class Item {
  Item({this.name, this.isFavorite});

  String name;
  bool isFavorite;
}

class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyListState();
}

class MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  List<Item> items;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Generate example items
    items = List<Item>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      items.add(Item(
        name: 'Item $i',
        isFavorite: false,
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListItem(
          items[index],
          () => onFavoritePressed(index),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  onFavoritePressed(int index) {
    final item = items[index];
    setState(() {
      item.isFavorite = !item.isFavorite;
    });
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  ListItem(this.item, this.onFavoritePressed);

  final Item item;
  final VoidCallback onFavoritePressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(item.name),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(item.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
        onPressed: onFavoritePressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When you call setState(), you rebuild the entire widget including the listView, would this cause it to flicker?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have many items in the `ListView` you can replace it with a `SingleChildScrollview` and a `Column` so that the Widgets aren't recycled. But it sounds like you should have a list of items where each item has an `isFavourite` property, and control the icon based on that property. Don't forget to `setState` when toggling the favorite.

Comment: What you did there doesn't make any sense. You created a stateful widget that doesn't store any state! Also, it does not solve OP's problem!

Comment: Even worse, if you store the state in the dynamic list items, it gets lost when the items leaves the viewport. Exactly the problem OP is describing.

Comment: @boformer Yeah whoops I got a little carried away imagining what op is doing. I removed the offending code.

Comment: I took the code you deleted to build something that actually works ;)

Answer (score 4):

Other answer are better for your case but this an alternative and can be used if you want to only keep several elements alive during a scroll. In this case you can use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin with keepAlive.

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FooState createState() {
    return new FooState();
  }
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  bool shouldBeKeptAlive = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    shouldBeKeptAlive = someCondition();
    return Container(

    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => shouldBeKeptAlive;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ListView.builder & GridView.builder makes items on demand. That means ,they construct item widgets & destroy them when they going beyond more than `cacheExtent`.

So you cannot keep any ephemeral state inside that item widgets.(So most of time item widgets are Stateless, but when you need to use `keepAlive` you use Stateful item widgets.

In this case you have to keep your state in a parent widget.So i think the best option you can use is **State management approach** for this. (like provider package, or scoped model).

Below link has similar Example i see in flutter.dev

[Link for Example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

*Hope this answer will help for you*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A problem with what you are doing is that when you change the `liked` variable, it exists in the Widget state and nowhere else. `ListView` items share Widgets so that only a little more than are visible at one time are created no matter how many actual items are in the data.

For a solution, keep a list of items as part of your home page's state that you can populate and refresh with real data. Then each of your `LikedClass` instances holds a reference to one of the actual list items and manipulates its data. Doing it this way only redraws only the `LikedClass` when it is tapped instead of the whole `ListView`.

```
class MyData {
  bool liked = false;
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<MyData> list;
  _MyHomePageState() {
    // TODO use real data.
    list = List<MyData>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) list.add(MyData());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new LikeClass(list[index]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LikeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyData data;

  LikeClass(this.data);

  @override
  _LikeClassState createState() => new _LikeClassState();
}

class _LikeClassState extends State<LikeClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: (() {
              setState(() {
                widget.data.liked = !widget.data.liked;
              });
            }),
            child: new Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              size: 24.0,
              color: widget.data.liked ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```