# Scrolling resets widgets flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an app with a bunch of text views inside a form. When the form scrolls, I lose the text entered in the above text fields. I would like to preserve those values. I tried adding a controller and assigning the value to a variable inside the state class but it does not work.

P.S not just widgets, but almost every type of input for example drop down buttons, radio buttons and what not.

Comment: add code whatever you tried.

Comment: I guess I know what the problem is, I have divided the forms into smaller ones for modularity. Those forms themselves are inside a list view. Reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071906/how-to-keep-the-state-of-my-widgets-after-scrolling, my guess is that ListView is destroying those forms when they are not visible destroying my state which is causing the problem @VirenVVarasadiya

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I just confirmed that. I set a breakpoint on the dispose method and by scrolling far enough, dispose is being called which is destroying my state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bunch of small forms inside a list view. Turns out, scrolling far enough, destroys the forms not visible to the user destroying their state. I need to lift their state up to the parent widget. For more information on how to do that, check [how to keep the state of my widgets after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071906/how-to-keep-the-state-of-my-widgets-after-scrolling)